# HAProxy set acl with hosts from file

Tags: haproxy

I'd like to migrate some 100+ sites from one server to another. Current plan is to gradually add an acl for each as they are moved to direct traffic to a new server.

Here is a simplified example

```
front http_frontend
  bind *:80
  acl is_new hdr_end(host) -i sub1.domain.com
  acl is_new hdr_end(host) -i sub2.domain.com
  acl is_new hdr_end(host) -i www.domain2.com
  mode http
  # etc
  use_backend web1 if is_new
  default_backend legacy1
```

Once they are all moved we'd change the `default_backend`

Is there a way to read these acls from another file? Or to read the domains from a file - perhaps something like this?

```
acl is_new hdr_end(host) -i /path/to/file
```

For instance, I include all the secure certificates as below, something like that'd be great!

```
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs.d
```

It's not the end of the world if not, it'd just be nice and tidy :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ACLs in haproxy can take `-f` argument to load values from a file. [You can read the documentation here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7).

For example:

`acl valid-ua hdr(user-agent) -f exact-ua.lst -i -f generic-ua.lst test`

> The "-f" flag is followed by the name of a file from which all lines
>   will be read as individual values. It is even possible to pass
>   multiple "-f" arguments if the patterns are to be loaded from multiple
>   files. Empty lines as well as lines beginning with a sharp ('#') will
>   be ignored.

Comment: Okay, I feel like a bit of a dick missing that. I now realise I had seen it in an example about blocking IPs but ended up thinking it was specific to that scenario. What a dummy! Thanks!